# chOwner and group permissions for PHP files and directories

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions, chown

What user and group ownership  should I set for php files and directories that not need to written to?

The root user OR the user that web server is running as?

Is it a good idea to set `chown root:$USER *` for these files and folders?

Comment: This is a duplicate, e.g., [What permissions should my website files/folders have on a Linux webserver?][1]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

Comment: @ThomasDickey So I should use `chown root:$USER *`? Thanks for you attention.

Comment: There are pros/cons to making files owned by root.  The downside is that maintenance of the website would have to be done with a privileged account (root).  Rather, providing a user (not root) who owns the files is the way to go.  Also, the user should be different from the webserver to guard against damage if the webserver itself is hacked.

Comment: In the chown command, the part after the ":" is a group name.  Making a file owned by root but having non-root group is not necessarily useful.

Answer (score 1):

as the ideal way is to set 644 permission to all files and 755 permission to all folders. for that you can use following command.

```
chmod 755 $(find /path/to/base/dir -type d)
chmod 644 $(find /path/to/base/dir -type f)
```

Hope it helps.

Thank you.